# APK size is big for an apk having a button and spinner only

Tags: android

I made an basic app containing spinner and button only,but its release mode size is 1.4 MB which i think is too big,cause lots of good apps available below 200kB also

So i tried in gradle file

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

First i added **shrinkrsources true** but nothing happened then i added **minifyEnabled true** size reduced to 800 KB ,

Then I tried **Android lint** by pressing

> ctrl + alt + shift +i

and typing Unused Resources ,nothing happened,

then i Tried in android studio

> Refactor > Remove Unused Resources

, still nothing happened

so i **change extention from .apk to .zip** and then extracted it then i found a res folder which is having lot of folders ,which are having lot of icons which are never used,I think those are reason for large size

So how to remove those icons during build so as to reduce apk size,

[res folder inside apk file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz8Xj.png)

[unused icons inside res > drawable folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se9vA.png)

build.gradle Module

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        resConfigs "en"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

}
```

build.gradle project

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: have you added material design dependencies for your project?? those icons are from material design dependency

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh I don't think so ,

Comment: `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0' }`

Comment: please share your `app` folder `build.gradle` file

Comment: @NiteshVerma added the `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1):

You can only reduce the size to around 200KB by removing `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1` from your `build.gradle`. This library is responsible for making app backward compatible so add bunch of extra code, style and assets which add up to around 4.5 MB on disk as shown.

[image: with support library][image: in disk][image: on disk size]

This library due to `proguard` compression end up being around 700 KB to your app size. So the 800KB you are getting is mostly `support` library.

If you remove this library you can have 200KB app but it might not be compatible with all android versions.